# MockMvc perform 'get' do not create JSESSIONID cookie

Tags: java, spring, junit, httpsession, mockmvc

I try to test my security layer using MockMvc. I've write the following integration test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ApplicationContextConfig.class,WebSecurityConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class AuthenticationStatesIT {

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext context;

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Before
  public void initMocks(){

     this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
           .addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(), "/*")
           .build();
   }

  @Test
  public void stage10_firstRequestForLoginPageShouldReturnProperPageAndAddUnauthenticatedStateToSession () throws Exception {

      MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                             .andDo(print())
                             //.andExpect(cookie().exists("JSESSIONID"))
                             .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection()).andReturn();

      MockHttpSession session = (MockHttpSession) mvcResult.getRequest().getSession();


      StatesAuthenticator authenticator = (StatesAuthenticator)session.getAttribute("authenticator");
      AuthenticationState state = authenticator.getState();

      Assert.assertNotNull(authenticator);
      Assert.assertNotNull(state);
  }
```

}

Everything work ok except one detail. The 'JSESSIONID' cookie is not creating. I am sure that the new session is created but the test 'andExpect(cookie().exists("JSESSIONID"))' is not passed. I am creating session as follows:

```
public class UnauthenticatedState implements AuthenticationState {

  @Override
  public void doAuthentication(StatesAuthenticator authentication,ServletRequest request, 
        ServletResponse response,FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

     authentication.setAuthentication(null);

     HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
     HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;

      //get the old session and invalidate if exists
       HttpSession oldSession = httpRequest.getSession(false);
       if (oldSession != null) {
           oldSession.invalidate();
       }
       //generate a new session
       HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(true);
       session.setMaxInactiveInterval(300); // 5 minutes
     session.setAttribute("authenticator", authentication);

     authentication.setState(new AuthenticatingState());

     httpResponse.sendRedirect("login");
  }
```

}

When I run server and look for that cookie in browser everything is ok, the cookie exists. Can someone explain me why MockMvc do no set 'JSESSIONID'? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Spring-Security by default create session only after authentication. That means if you need cookie in your test, you should authenticate. Or you can try put some property in to your application.properties and Spring will create session cookie for every session.

Comment: I am not using Spring-Security. I am createing own way for user authentication. As far as I know the method httpRequest.getSession(true) will create a new session which should create JSESSIONID cookie too.